# Rendering into GLX back buffer with X calls?

Tags: c, graphics, x11, glx

I'm playing around with GLX and xlib and I'm curious about rendering using straight X calls on top of an openGL buffer.  The glx [intro](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glXIntro.xml) clearly says that:

> GLX extended X servers make a subset of their visuals available for OpenGL rendering. Drawables created with these visual can also be rendered into using the core X renderer and or any other X extension that is compatible with all core X visuals.

And, indeed, I'm able to render a simple quad colored with some rainbow effects and then draw on top of it with xlib calls.  *However*, GLX extends the X window with a back buffer, which I have to swap to the front before I can then directly render to the window.  My question is: is it possible to use X to render to the *back* buffer after openGL is done with it and then swap that buffer wholesale to the front, thus giving me flicker free animation on both my openGL and X graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no, but there are maybe some alternatives.

You could do another layer of double-buffering with a pixmap (render X and GL to a pixmap, then draw the pixmap to your X window). It probably wrecks your framerate if you were doing an FPS game but for what you describe might not matter.

You could also use Cairo to draw to a client-side memory buffer, with alpha channel for the background to show through. Then upload the result as a texture to GL and paint it over your background. The Clutter toolkit does this for some of its drawing.